# Как преобразовать QString в std::string?

Tags: c++, qt, преобразование-типов, qstring

Я пытался сделать так:

```
QString string;
// делаю так ...
std::cout << string << std::endl;
```

Но проблема, код не собирается.Как выводить содержимое qstring в консоль (например, для целей отладки или по другим причинам)? Как преобразовать QString в std::string?

Этот вопрос, перевод вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214369/how-to-convert-qstring-to-stdstring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одна вещь которую надо помнить, при преобразовании QString в std::string это то что QString кодируется в кодировке UTF-16, а std :: string ... Может иметь любые кодировки.

Вот лучшие способы:

```
QString qs;

// можно использовать такой способ если пользуетесь UTF-8 в любом месте
std::string utf8_text = qs.toUtf8().constData();

// или таким способом если вы в Windows :-)
std::string current_locale_text = qs.toLocal8Bit().constData();
```

Предлагаемый (принятый) метод может работать, если вы укажете кодек.

Смотри: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1

---

Ты можешь использовать:

```
QString qs;
// делай так
std::cout << qs.toStdString() << std::endl;
```

Вот   справочная [документация](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdString) для `QString`.

---

Если ваша конечная цель - получить отладочные сообщения на консоли, вы можете использовать qDebug ().

Вы можете использовать,

```
#include <QDebug> // в заголовке файла (.cpp либо .h)

qDebug() << "строка"; // выводим надпись на консоль
QString str = "строка";
qDebug() << str; // выводим надпись на консоль
```

Этот способ лучше, чем преобразование его в `std :: string` , но только для отладки сообщений *(либо использовать в создаваемом приложении как реперные точки(так сказать такой "полудебагер") )*.

`qDebug()` для отладки сообщений намного лучше, потому что он поддерживает больше типов Qt

---

```
QString qstr;
std::string str = qstr.toStdString();
```

Однако, если вы используете Qt:

```
QTextStream out(stdout);
out << qstr;
```

---

Лучший способ это перегрузить оператор << ,так что бы QString можно передать как тип в любую библиотеку.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const QString& string) {
    return str << string.toStdString();
}
```

---

Альтернатива предлагаемому:

```
QString qs;
std :: string current_locale_text = qs.toLocal8Bit (). constData ();
```

еще может быть:

```
QString qs;
std :: string current_locale_text = qPrintable (qs);
```

Смотри документацию [qPrintable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qPrintable), макрос предоставляющий const char * из QtGlobal.

---

Простейший способ ,это  `QString::toStdString()`.

---

Вы можете использовать, это :

```
QString data;
data.toStdString().c_str();
```

---

*Примечания переводчика : сам использую для вывода в консоль `qDebug()`.*